# How to know that whether a tap is inside a view or outside in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, point

I'm try to develop code part, to check whether mine tap is inside a view or outside a view, i tried with pointInside method. If A is main View Controller and B is subView of A, How can i get to know that user tapped inside B.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Apple explains it very well in [Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html). You can add the following function to your view controller:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let firstTouch = touches.first {
        let hitView = self.view.hitTest(firstTouch.location(in: self.view), with: event)

        if hitView === viewB {
            print("touch is inside")
        } else {
            print("touch is outside")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: missing argument for parameter 'with' in call. i didn't get it.

Comment: Do we need to set some delegate? Since it is not getting fired.

Comment: if hitView != viewB {
            print("is outside the view")
        }

maybe would help someone)

Answer (score 17):

In the `tapGestureRecognizer` callback you can use the method `tapGesture.location(in: A)` in order to fetch the x, y position of the A referral system. Then you can use `B.frame.contains(location)`.

If true, then the tap is in B.

Depending on what you want to do there are simpler approaches to the problem. For example, you could add the `gestureRecognizer` to B instead of A, if you are interested just in touches inside B.

I don't know which are exactly your needs. With more info I could give you better advices.

Comment: If with this methods use:
convertPoint:
     fromView:
it would be really useful.